# Python 3 retrieve numbers from file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I'm having problems in my Python coursework as I can't figure out how to retrieve numbers from a file and add them together.

This is my code so far:

```
 bmi = "1500"
 bmr = "2000"



 reg_invalid_file = open("dataforcomputingCW.csv", "a")
 writeRecord = bmi + "|" + bmr + "\n" 
 reg_invalid_file.write( writeRecord )
 reg_invalid_file.close()

 reg_invalid_file = open("dataforcomputingCW.csv" , "r" )
 all_records = reg_invalid_file.read()
 reg_invalid_file.close()

 pa = all_records.split("\n")
 for i in len(pa):
     bmi_bmr = pa[i].split("|")
     total_bmi = total_bmi + bmi_bmr[i]
     print (total_bmi)

 bmi_bmr = any[i].split("|")
 total_bmi = totalbmi + bmibmr[0]
 total_bmr = totalbmr + bmibmr[1]

 print (totalbmi)
```

and in the file the numbers should look like this:

```
 1500|2000

 1500|2000
```

I need to add the bmi and print then add bmr then print so user can see total bmi and bmr seperately.

Comment: `i need to add the bmi and print then add bmr then print ` Add what to bmi, and print what? Please be more precise

Comment: Just use a [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to tokenise the file and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: i just need to add the numbers together in the file

Answer (score -1):

If you can not use the csv module, you might want to consider the [sscanf](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/scanf/) script. (Or since your task is simple, use the scanf script)

```
import scanf
a,b = scanf.sscanf(reg_invalid_file.readline(), "%d|%d ")
```